# Jmeter getHeaderManager() command adding too many headers to the request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a Jmeter test which accepts auth Token header and added to the http request using the below command

```
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("BEARER")));
```

Its working fine for first few requests and then failing with below error

```
HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long
```

When I checked the header, it was actually added around 100+ headers for Auth Token [:O]. Please see  details below. Could some one help me on this.

[image]

[image: +]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that you call `HeaderManager#add` over and over again. The method `add` adds a header. While what you really want to do, is to replace a header. Sadly there is no method on the `HeaderManager` to do so.

But you can emulate it. First remove all headers named `Authorization` from the header manager and after that re-add the header with the new value. The code in Groovy would look like this:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header
sampler.headerManager.removeHeaderNamed('Authorization')
sampler.headerManager.add(new Header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + vars.get('BEARER')))
```

Comment: How would it look if used JavaScript please

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your [JSR223 Preprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) is placed in incorrect location.

JSR223 PreProcessor obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) therefore if you put it at the same level as multiple [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) it will be executed **before each Sampler in its scope**.

So you need to make the JSR223 PreProcessor a child of the Sampler which header you want to modify and it should resolve your problem.

By the way, you don't need any scripting, headers can be added using [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).